# Expression Tree construction?

Tags: data-structures

Construct the expression tree for the following expression:

```
E=(2a+5b)(x-7y)^4
```

I can construct it without the ^4 .

How it can be constructed for this type of operator?

my effort:

```
           *
        /     \
       /       \
      +         ^
     / \       /  \
    /   \     -    4
   *     *   / \ 
 /  \   / \  x  * 
2    a 5   b   /  \
              7    y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Degree is just another binary operator so not a big difference there. Just keep in mind it usually has higher priority than other operations.

Comment: Can you show the tree you construct? Without the `^`. I need to see some effort - the point is not that I do your homework after all.

Comment: actually i think degree is unary operator.Image can't be posted as my point is below 10.

Comment: degree is not an unary operator. It is binary. That is why you write: `x^y` not just `^y`.

Comment: I think the problem gets solved .I can't show my effort to you as I can't post images here.Thanks for your last comment.

Comment: @TanmoyBanerjee yeap seems correct to me. Well done! You came up with the answer yourself which is twice as good for you ;)

Comment: The answer of my problem is your 2nd comment-"degree is not an unary operator. It is binary. That is why you write: x^y not just ^y. – Ivaylo Strandjev.".Thanks a lot.